# In Ruby, is an if/elsif/else statement's subordinate block the same as a 'block' that is passed as a parameter?

Tags: ruby, terminology, control-flow

I was doing some reading on if/elsif/else in Ruby, and I ran into some differences in terminology when describing how control expressions work.

In the [Ruby Programming Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures) (emphasis added):

> A conditional Branch takes the result of a test expression and executes a **block of code** depending whether the test expression is true or false.

and

> An if expression, for example, not only determines whether a **subordinate block of code** will execute, but also results in a value itself.

Ruby-doc.org, however, does not mention blocks at all in the definitions:

> The simplest if expression has two parts, a “test” expression and a “then” **expression**. If the “test” expression evaluates to a true then the “then” expression is evaluated.

Typically, when I have read about 'blocks' in Ruby, it has almost always been within the context of procs and lambdas. For example, rubylearning.com defines a block:

> A Ruby **block** is a way of grouping statements, and may appear only in the source adjacent to a method call; the **block** is written starting on the same line as the method call's last parameter (or the closing parenthesis of the parameter list).

The questions:

- When talking about blocks of code in Ruby, are we talking about
  the group of code that gets passed in to a method or are we simply
  talking about a group of code in general?
- Is there a way to easily differentiate between the two (and is there
  a technical difference between the two)?

Context for these questions: I am wondering if referring to the code inside of conditionals as *blocks* will be confusing to to new Ruby programmers when they are later introduced to blocks, procs, and lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR `if...end` is an expression, not a block

The proper use of the term `block` in Ruby is the code passed to a method in between `do...end` or curly braces `{...}`. A block can be and often is implicitly converted into a `Proc` within a method by using the `&block` syntax in the method signature. This new `Proc` is an object with its own methods that can be passed to other methods, stored in variables and data structures, called repeatedly, etc...

```
def block_to_proc(&block)
  prc = block
  puts prc
  prc.class
end

block_to_proc { 'inside the block' }
# "#<Proc:0x007fa626845a98@(irb):21>"
# => Proc
```

In the code above, a `Proc` is being implicitly created with the block as its body and assigned to the variable `block`. Likewise, a `Proc` (or a `lambda`, a type of `Proc`) can be "expanded" into blocks and passed to methods that are expecting them, by using the `&block` syntax at the end of an arguments list.

```
def proc_to_block
  result = yield # only the return value of the block can be saved, not the block itself
  puts result
  result.class
end

block = Proc.new { 'inside the Proc' }

proc_to_block(&block)
# "inside the Proc"
# => String
```

Although there's somewhat of a two-way street between `block`s and `Proc`s, they're not the same. Notice that to define a `Proc` we had to pass a `block` to `Proc.new`. Strictly speaking a `block` is just a chunk of code passed to a method whose execution is deferred until explicitly called. A `Proc` is defined with a `block`, its execution is also deferred until called, but it is a bonafide object just like any other. A `block` cannot survive on its own, a `Proc` can.

On the other hand, `block` or `block of code` is sometimes casually used to refer to any discreet chunk of code enclosed by Ruby keywords terminating with `end`: `if...else...end`, `begin...rescue...end`, `def...end`, `class...end`, `module...end`, `until...end`. But these are not really blocks, per se, and only really resemble them on the surface. Often they also have deferred execution until some condition is met. But they can stand entirely on their own, and always have return values. Ruby-doc.org's use of "expression" is more accurate.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science))

> An expression in a programming language is a combination of one or
>   more explicit values, constants, variables, operators, and functions
>   that the programming language interprets (according to its particular
>   rules of precedence and of association) and computes to produce ("to
>   return", in a stateful environment) another value.

This is why you can do things like this

```
return_value = if 'expression'
  true
end

return_value # => true
```

Try doing that with a block

```
return_value = do
  true
end

# SyntaxError: (irb):24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
# return_value = do
#                  ^
```

A block is not an expression on its own. It needs either `yield` or a conversion to a `Proc` to survive. What happens when we pass a block to a method that doesn't want one?

```
puts("indifferent") { "to blocks" }
# "indifferent"
# => nil
```

The block is totally lost, it disappears with no return value, no execution, as if it never existed. It needs `yield` to complete the expression and produce a return value.

```
class Object
  def puts(*args)
    super
    yield if block_given?
  end
end

puts("mindful") { "of blocks" }
# "mindful"
# => "of blocks"
```